# change all controls in other c# Visual Studio Project programmatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there any way to change a property of all Buttons in All Forms of a visual studio project programmatically?

for example I want to change the back color of all Buttons in all Windows Forms to Red and save them. so when I open the project again in visual studio all buttons in all forms have Red Back color.

because my changes will be complicated I can not do it by open .designer.cs files and replace the backcolor values of each button.

is there any way to do it programmatically?

Comment: A free tool like GrepWin can operate on multiple files/folders simultaneously, and you can use regular expressions, so you might be able to get it to use a regex to recognise the markup for buttons in the files and replace the right part of the markup with the changed background property value.

Comment: You can do this by overriding the Button class.

Comment: @Mehmood that will still entail changing all existing button code in every file so that it uses the overriden version. So the stated problem of easily updating all of the references across multiple files would still exist.